# retainAll changes the last element

Tags: java, collections

```
List<Left> resultList = lists.iterator().next();
    for (Iterator iterator = lists.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        List<Left> list = (List<Left>) iterator.next();         
        resultList.retainAll(list);
    }

    /*for (Left left : resultList) {
         System.out.println(left.getData());
    }*/

    for (Left left : mLeft) {           
        ArrayList<Left> mTempList = left.getArray();    
        for (Iterator iterator = mTempList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Left left2 = (Left) iterator.next();
            System.out.println(left2.getData());
        }
    }
```

I am trying to find out the common elements , my original list is getting changed.I mean only last element gets changed when I print the lists.
Any suggestions.

Comment: Give example input and output please...

Comment: If possible give more relevant code. Couple of questions arises. What is mLeft? lists seems "list of list of type Left". But still the code and logic is ambiguous. Please post more code.

Answer (score 1):

`resultList` gets assigned to the first element in your collection `lists` right at the top.

On line 4 you execute `retainAll` against `resultList` without changing what `resultList` is assigned to - it's still pointing to the first object in `lists`.

You might consider creating a new `List<Left>` object to check for the common elements, right at the start instead of how you've declared `resultList`:

```
List<Left> resultList = new List<Left>();
resultList.addAll ((List<Left>) lists.iterator().next());
...
```

You would then want to use resultList in the final loop when you print out the elements.

Note that you are still assuming that `lists` has at least one element - if it's empty you'll get an exception.